# Unable to load HTTP URL Image

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I'm trying to convert a watchOS 1 app to watchOS 2.
But I saw an error when trying to load an image from an URL with this code:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxx/xyz.jpg")!
let data:NSData = try! NSData(contentsOfURL:url, options:[])
imageone.setImage(UIImage(data: data))
```

The error is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “xyz.jpg” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxx/xyz.jpg}

I read on the internet that this is because of the new Application Transport Security protocol.
I also read to put

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

in the info.plist on the Watchkit extension but the same error appear.
It's the same also if I use an image in an HTTPS domain.

> NOTE: On the simulator it works perfectly!

I'm using XCode 7 beta 5.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

> UPDATE
>   Looking around the web I found that maybe with NSURLSession I will solve the problem but I did not found nothing useful on this.
>   Can someone help me to convert my code to the NSURLSession syntax?
>   Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the image exists? I feel like this is an issue with the URL specifically...

Comment: @Idris Yes, I tried with different images on HTTP or HTTPS and on the Mac browser works and also on my project executed in the simulator it's working

Comment: i just faced this, make sure to NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in both info.plist ( app and Watchki extention... ) and clean project

Comment: @Jeremy Luisetti I just tried but it didn't works. People say that it need to be added only on the extension. In the simulator works perfectly

Comment: Anyone else knows how to solve this issue? Or maybe it's a known bug?

Comment: Seems that watchOS 2 Beta 5 have a big bug. All outbound TCP connections seems to be blocked. I need to wait next beta

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way of achieving that with `NSSession` in Objective-C. It should not be difficult to translate it in Swift

```
NSString *dataUrl = @"http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxx/xyz.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];

NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage initWithData:data];
    // Do what you like with your image
}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved creating a function:

```
func imageRequest(urlweb:NSURL) {

    let requestURL: NSURL = urlweb
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            NSLog("Success!")
            self.imagename?.setImage(UIImage(data:data!))

        } else {

            NSLog("Fail")

        }

    }

    task.resume()

}
```